# In MVP pattern how to access specified view component in Presenter?

Tags: android, rx-java, observable

SignUpFragment uses SignUpPresenter and SignUpFragment inplements SignUpView. SingUpPresenter  extends BasePresenter
where BasePresenter:

```
public abstract class BasePresenter<V> {

private WeakReference<V> mView;

public void bindView(@NonNull V view) {
    mView = new WeakReference<>(view);
    if (setupDone()) {
        updateView();
    }
}

public void unbindView() {
    mView = null;
}

protected V view() {
    if (mView == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return mView.get();
    }
}

protected abstract void updateView();

private boolean setupDone() {
    return view() != null;
}
}

public interface SignUpView extends BaseView {
void showResult(UserInfo result);
}
```

SignUpPresenter connects with SignUpFragment via view() like:

```
view().showResult()
view().showError()
```

I want to know if in SignUpPresenter I want to add validation via RxAndroid:

```
Observable<CharSequence> loginObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mEmail);
```

I mean I want to have access to mEmail of SignUpFragment in SignUpPresenter. Is it ok to add method in SignFramgnet method like:

```
public EditText getEditTextEmail(){return mEmail;}
```

Which I could use in SignUpPresenter like `mEail = view().getEditTextEmail();`

Or I need to add all this part in Activity/Fragment:

```
 Observable<CharSequence> loginObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mLogin);
 loginObservable
    .map(this::isValidLogin)
    .subscribe(isValid -> mLogin.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null, (isValid ? mValidField : mInvalidField), null));
```

Comment: Normally your Presenter should know nothing about Android, so using `RxTextView` inside a Presenter looks out of place.

Comment: Great! In such case we need to add all this in Framgnet/Activity ?
Observable<CharSequence> emailObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mEmail);
emailObservable
        .map(this::isValidEmail)
        .subscribe(isValid -> mEmail.setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(null,null, (isValid ? mValidField : mInvalidField), null));

Comment: Yes, this all looks like UI code to me. If you want your Presenter to validate the email, you can just map against `presenter.isValidEmail()`.

Comment: @Egor the part of Observable confused me, you mean  it is ok to put code of Observable in Activity/Fragment ?

Comment: Definitely, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `loginObservable` in your View and pass it to Presenter. `Observable<CharSequence>` is not a part of Android Framework so it can be easily unit-tested.

```
//View
Observable<CharSequence> loginObservable = RxTextView.textChanges(mEmail);
presenter.setLoginObservable(loginObservable);

//Presenter
void setLoginObservable(Observable<CharSequence> observable) {
    observable
        .map(this::isValidLogin) 
        .subscribe(isValid -> {
            //call appropriate view methods
        });
```

Comment: I see in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QdmkXL7XikQ  2:40 that as we working with immutable streams like loginObservables= RxTextView.textChanges(mEmail) and then loginObservables.map(this::isValidLogin)  and RxTextView.textChanges(mEmail).map(this::isValidLogin) are different,like it is not good idea to separate them
What do you think?

Comment: We have to separate in order to pass observable to Presenter.